# painting a rectangular roof

Tags: geometry

A barn with a roof is rectangular in shape, 10 yd. wide, 13 yd. long and 5 yd. high. It is to be painted inside and outside, and on the ceiling, but not on the roof or floor. The total number of sq. yd. to be painted is?....

Comment: I calculated the total surface area but my answer is incorrect

Comment: What is the calculation you did?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please show your work, so we can point out your mistake.  You'll find that questions like this, that just state a problem and show no work, are not well-received on this site.

Comment: I calculated total surface area of cuboid... 2x(lb+bh+hl)... My answer is 490 but the book shows its 590

Comment: And how about the part that says 'not on the roof or floor'?

Comment: How did you take account of painting on both the inside and outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have instead found the number of square yards to be painted if only the inside is to be painted, including the floor. However, this is not what you've been asked to do.

Let's imagine that the barn has walls on the North, East, South, and West, for ease of discussion. You can orient it however you like, so that the North and South walls are either $10\times 5$ or $13\times 5$ in dimension.

Since the North and South walls are identical in dimension, and must be painted both inside and out, then we must paint $4$ times the outer area of one of those walls. Similarly, we must paint $4$ times the outer area of the East or West wall. In this manner, all the walls will be painted as desired.

Finally, we must paint the ceiling's area. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yeah☺️ thanks..................